# How join (merge) 2 duplicate projects in local files

Tags: git, version-control

I only have git local. So, I have my project in my machine. Than, I copy and paste all files of project (so the gits files was there) in another computer and make commits. Then make commits in my computer.

So I have this situation:

```
#Computer 1
   |A => Make a lot of comits
   | =>Duplicate all file here

#Computer 2
   |B => Make other commits
   | =>Duplicate all file here
```

I want do this, join the 2 project and create 2 different branch

```
  |A    |B
   \   /
     | => Duplicate all files here
```

Then I can easy merge using the common merge of 2 branch

```
     |C => Merged,
   /   \
  |A    |B
   \   /
     | => Duplicate all files here
```

How can I do this: Join 2 duplicate project in 2 branch with local files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make on each repository a remote of the other project: either by file sharing or copying back both repositories on the same computer.

```
$git remote add computer2 <path-to-other>
```

Then fetch changes

```
$git fetch computer2
```

At this point you have your local branch and the other branch, as remote branch

Merge the remote branch back with

```
$git merge computer2/master
```

Comment: Great! Work. I use the smartgit but it didn't have this option. Using command line work prefect. Thanks.